# PHP Laravel display array as HTML

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm quite new to PHP Blade/Laravel and I'm trying to display an array, which is inside an variable, as HTML.

So I got an variable named `$products` and first of all I did this:

```
{{ print_r($products) }}
```

This gave me:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Belt
        [image] => img/products/belt.jpg
        [price] => 79.00
        [specialPrice] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Hat
        [image] => img/products/hat.jpg
        [price] => 89.00
        [specialPrice] => 69.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Bag
        [image] => img/products/bag.jpg
        [price] => 99.00
        [specialPrice] => 59.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Scarf
        [image] => img/products/scarf.jpg
        [price] => 119.00
        [specialPrice] => 
    )

 )
1
```

So, I want to display this Array as HTML. I tried this:

```
 @foreach($products as $key => $item)
      <p>{{@item->title}}</p>
 @endforeach
```

But that didnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `->` is for objects `[]` or `{}` are for arrays. e.g. `$item['title']` i think would do it. Also I'm not familiar with laravel but it can have HTML in the PHP directly?

Comment: Chris85 is right, just use the square brackets to show the attributes.

Comment: when I write `<p>{{@item['title']}}</p>` I get `<p>i</p>` ??

Comment: @chris85 ah actually `<p>{{@item['title']}}</p>` seemed to work. probably some caching issue :-s Now, is there any way to sort from a-z?

Comment: Sort the titles? You'd have to do that at the array creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@foreach($products as $product)
      <p>{{$product->title}}</p> 
 @endforeach
```

or this

```
@foreach($products as $product)
          <p>{{$product[title]}}</p> 
     @endforeach
```